# 411 content length error in PHP using google api

Tags: php, google-api

I'm trying to send a simple post request to the api to download a report.

And getting a 411 error message which says "POST requests require a content-length header. That's all we know."

I'm using the example in here.
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/wiki/NoClientLibrary

Also tried the new api url
https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201309

Has anybody ever come across with this?
Any ideas?

Thanks!

```
<?php
// Provide header information.
$authToken = 'INSERT_AUTH_TOKEN_HERE';
$clientCustomerId = 'INSERT_CLIENT_CUSTOMER_ID_HERE';
$developerToken = 'INSERT_DEVELOPER_TOKEN_HERE';

// Create report definition XML.
$reportDefinition = <<<EOT
<reportDefinition xmlns="https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/cm/v201109">
  <selector>
    <fields>CampaignId</fields>
    <fields>Id</fields>
    <fields>Impressions</fields>
    <fields>Clicks</fields>
    <fields>Cost</fields>
    <predicates>
      <field>Status</field>
      <operator>IN</operator>
      <values>ENABLED</values>
      <values>PAUSED</values>
    </predicates>
  </selector>
  <reportName>Custom Adgroup Performance Report</reportName>
  <reportType>ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT</reportType>
  <dateRangeType>LAST_7_DAYS</dateRangeType>
  <downloadFormat>CSV</downloadFormat>
</reportDefinition>
EOT;

// Create parameters.
$params = array('__rdxml' => $reportDefinition);

// Create headers.
$headers = array();
$headers[]= 'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $authToken;
$headers[]= 'clientCustomerId: ' . $clientCustomerId;
$headers[]= 'developerToken: ' . $developerToken;
$headers[]= 'content-length: ' . trim(strlen(print_r($params, true)));
$headers[]= 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';

$downloadPath = 'report.csv';
$url = 'https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/reportdownload/v201109';

$file = fopen($downloadPath, 'w');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($file);

if ($code == 200) {
  printf("Report downloaded to: %s\n", $downloadPath);
} else {
  $file = fopen($downloadPath, 'r');
  $error = fread($file, 1024);
  fclose($file);
  printf("Error: %s\n", $error);
}
```

Comment: try content-length replacing content_length at $headers[]= 'content_length: ' . trim(strlen(print_r($params, true)));

Comment: it actually is content-length in the code, i mis-typed here